# Hello world crashing

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I wrote a simple hello world in kotlin and it keeps giving me this error:

Main.kts:3:10: warning: parameter 'args' is never used
fun main(args : Array) {

I'm at a loss for what could be the issue. I'm using the latest version of "Ultimate Intellij" and my guess is it must be some sort of issue with the ide. Below is all my code. I'm using the java 8 sdk, with kotlin 1.2

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
println("Hello, world!")
 }
```

Comment: That's a warning. Does it actually *crash* like the title says?

Comment: Please define "crashing".

Comment: It never prints "Hello, world!", so I'm assuming it crashes. It is either that or it isn't executing main for some reason

Comment: @ChandlerCoates are you actually *running* the code, or just compiling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the following issues:

You created a Kotlin script (kts file) instead of a Kotlin class (kt file). The main method is not called in Kotlin scripts. You should make an explicit call to the main method or other available methods. (it's a scripting file like a bash script).

The warning is correct. The args argument is not used ;-)